# Probability- $L^2 \implies \max$ tail inequality

Tags: probability, rate-of-convergence

I wonder if anyone can give a hint about whether the following is correct or wrong.

If given a probability measure $P$, $D \in L^2(P)$ is a function. Is it true that 
$$ \max_{1\leq i\leq n} D(X_i) = o_p(n^{1/2}) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true if $(D(X_i))_{i=1}^\infty$ is an i.i.d. sequence of $L^2$-random variables. 
 As a hint, estimate
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb P\left(|D(X_i)|^2\ge \epsilon^2 i\right)=\Bbb E[|D(X_1)|^2]/\epsilon^2 + O(1)
$$ and deduce that
$$
\frac{\max_{i\le n}|D(X_i)|}{n^{1/2}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}_p 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I might be using too weak an estimation but by Chebyshev inequality, I can see that $$\sum P(|D|^2\geq \epsilon^2 i ) \leq E[|D|^2]/\epsilon^2 \sum\frac{1}{i}$$, the harmonic series is divergent and not bounded. Can you please give some clarification?

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote the hint, but I'll explain it in more detail. For any non-negative random variable $X$ with the distribution $F(t)=\Bbb P(X \le t)$, it holds that$$
\Bbb E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1−F(t)) \ dt=\int_0^\infty \Bbb P(X>t) \ dt.$$
So, by the non-decreasing nature of $F$, we have
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\Bbb P(X\ge n)\le \Bbb E[X] \le \sum_{n\ge 0} \Bbb P(X\ge n).$$
This proves the first part. For the second part, apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma. You may find that $$
|D(X_i)|<\epsilon \sqrt{i}\ \ \text{ all but finite } i$$
and this implies the desired result.